# how to send parameter to the action of another controller through url in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to send parameter to the action of another controller through url in rails?

controller1:

```
def show
  @controller1.id = params[:controller1_id]
end
```

in the view of controller1:

```
%a.btn-general{:href => "/controller2/new/#{parameteroffirst.id}", :controller1_id @controller1.id,  :role => "button"} Add the first
```

how to send `controller1.id` to `new` action of `controller2`?

Comment: seems like you are trying to get id in `controller2#new`  if someone clicks `anchor` tag ?

Comment: Yes I need parameter of controller1 in the new action of controller2

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to write it out like this, try changing:

```
:href => "/controller2/new/#{parameteroffirst.id}", :controller1_id @controller1.id
```

To:

```
:href => "/controller2/new?controller1_id=#{parameteroffirst.id}"
```

But it's really worth your reading up on how links are supposed to work in ruby / rails:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: :href => "/controller2/new?controller1_id=#{parameteroffirst.id}", :role => "button"  It is not working

Answer (score 0):

A good practice in rails is to use named routes instead of string urls.

```
%a.btn-general{href: url_for(controller: :controller2, action: :new, id: parameteroffirst.id, controller1_id: @controller1.id), role: "button"} Add the first
```

It will generate an url like `/controller2/new/#{parameteroffirst.id}?controller1_id=#{@controller1.id}`. but you can change the route tomorrow without the need to go all over your code changing the hardcoded links.